# Joomla AEC component trigger user updation

Tags: components, joomla2.5

I have installed the AEC(Account Expiration Control) component in my Joomla(2.5) website. I want to add a micro-integration script to run when the User register to the site or while updating the profile information. I have checked the example integration script and found that the

> on_userchange_action

method is triggered when user register or update his details.

How can I trigger this method when editing a user using Admin user. I have tried to edit the user in 3 places.

1. Joomla User Manager
2. Jom Social User Manager
3. AEC Members

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to trigger the method when you make a change from the admin area?

Comment: Yes Brent. I want to know when it gets triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with AEC but to trigger an action you can check if building a plugin that is triggred by for example by:

> onUserAfterSave

Comment: Thank you vdespa. The AEC plugin was using the old event name, that was causing this issue. I have used the event name as onBeforUserSave.

Answer (score 1):

Several events have been renamed for Joomla 2.5, here is the list of current Joomla event triggers -

http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin#Events

The one you are looking for is probably `onAfterStoreUser`